# If something is true for general value then how it is true for other values?

Tags: logic

If something is true for n how its true for every value.
For example,
If eqn of line is ,
Y=mx+c.
You have proved this eqn for m and c.what is the logic or reasoning that its true for -3 and 2?
Then if i ask you equation of line whose slope is=-3 and c=2
Then you will directly substitute the values in the equation.But can you give me logic behind it.(how the substituted equation is of that line)Or i may die due to this confusion.
Please refer to this,
[How we put values in formulas to get answers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574377/how-we-put-values-in-formulas-to-get-answers)

Comment: Look up [universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)

Comment: Doesn't a 'general value' take into account all possible 'other values'?

Comment: We prove that, in the Cartesian plane, the [general equation of a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#On_the_Cartesian_plane) is: $y=mx+c$.

Comment: Here "general" means that, for every value of the "parameters" $m$ and $c$ a specific line will be identified.

Comment: Probably, the simplest way to derive it (the equation) is through *vector algebra*; see e.g. T.Apostol, [Calculus I](http://plouffe.fr/simon/Phys%20et%20Math/Calculus%201%20Tom%20A%20Apostol.pdf), page 471-on

Comment: Having said that, the correct answer is the first one above: "what is true for every member of a class of individuals is true for a particular individual of that class".

Comment: I think that, if you write down exactly what you mean by "general value" and by "true for general value", then you will have answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "let $m$ be a number" already encodes the idea that you can substitute a value $2,3,\pi,...$ into $m$. But why do we do that? Why do we write a letter instead of the number itself?

Observations:

$$2^2-1^2=4-1=3=3\times1=(2+1)(2-1)$$
$$3^2-2^2=9-4=5=5\times1=(3+2)(3-2)$$
$$4^2-2^2=16-4=12=6\times2=(4+2)(4-2)$$

There is something there. You see? We want to say something, but we don't really know how to say it, and once you learn how to use the symbols, the thing is said simply:

Question: is it true that $\forall a,b:a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$?

The algebraic structure is firstly a language. The logic is its grammar. The essence of substitution is the meaning of the language.

---

Nevertheless, in order to understand the language, you might need at first to learn its seemingly arbitrary law (e.g. universal instantiation, axiom of choice, etc).

Comment: You are almighty.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just learning to be a good teacher.

Comment: By the way don't forget to upvote and check on the correct-answer tick :)

Comment: Can you tell me if I want to more clearly understand this.What should I do.

Comment: You can pick up a book on logic and start reading when you have time. I suspect googling "logic math book recommendation" would give you many suggestions. Be careful not to click on any suspected link. Google can be a dangerous space. Try links with math.stackexchange first.